# Converting mp3 and video content so I can listen to it on my iphone

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts, mp3

If I find a MP3 audio on the internet, or a MP3 video (or even YouTube), is it possible save this on my iPhone somehow so I can listen to it?

Not sure but I believe iTunes has a special format.

Comment: Do you want to save it directly on your iPhone using the mobile Safari browser, or would you also accept solutions which download and convert the video/audio file on your Mac/PC and then sync the music to your iPhone?

Comment: @gentmatt just looking for possible solutions, not set on any single method.

Answer (score 1):

iTunes plays both MP3 and AAC.

You can import one of theme and convert to the other by right-clicking on a song and selecting "*create MP3 version*" (or "*create AAC version*").

In iTunes you can set you can set the preferred format in the "*import settings*" (Preferences -> General -> Import Settings...).

Once they are in iTunes you can sync them on your iPhone or iPad.

For song found on YouTube you can google for "YouTube to MP3". You will find something (I'm not sure I can post a direct link here).

Answer (score 0):

I use Handbrake for converting files - but if the device is jailbroken, then applications like Protube (and just recently `Bridge' will do a lot of the conversation for you on the phone...